# handle two loss functions in KERAS

Tags: keras, loss-function

is it possible in Keras to have two different loss functions in training for two separate reservoirs (m/n in example below)?[image]

Comment: Yes, its possible to have two loss functions, but what do you mean by reservoirs here?

Comment: the samples from one reservoir should just affect the first loss function and the samples from the other reservoir only the other loss function.

Comment: the reservoirs used was generated from self play between the agents.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you say with Reservoirs, maybe add some code?

Comment: this is what the reservoir looks like: `reservoir = deque(maxlen=30000000)`

Comment: I'm using a technique called fictional self play. Reservoir sampling is used to ensure the reservoir contains an even distribution of the training data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have two loss functions in keras. Let  say you have `loss_1` and `loss_2` functions with `w1` and `w2` weights. You can enforce this in keras as follows.

```
model.compile(loss=[loss_1, loss_2], loss_weights=[w1,w2], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the samples from one reservoir should just affect loss_1 and the samples from the other reservoir only loss_2.

Comment: what do you mean by reservoir?

Comment: it is a buffer where the samples from the fictional self play are stored.